# why images not showing horizontally in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to show images horizontally using css but it did not work ?

can anyone suggest on how to show images horizontally using css ?

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/urLdLdLm/3/

i tried :

```
.outer {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto;
.outer li img{ display: inline-block;}
```

```css
.outer {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
.outer li img{ display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
    <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA"></li>
     <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
 <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the `display: inline-block` on the `.outer li`, not `.outer li img`

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i tried like that but it is not working

Comment: It does: https://jsfiddle.net/urLdLdLm/5/. If that doesn't work in your case check the elements in the DOM inspector to see what other CSS rules are being applied to them, and from where

Comment: here is a link : https://jsfiddle.net/urLdLdLm/4/, and it's working fine.

Comment: I think space issue ..Thanks got

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use `flexbox` to accomplish that

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd">
    </li>
    <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA">
    </li>
    <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd">
    </li>
    <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are not your images, but the list, which by default displays its `li` children underneath each other.

```
.outer li,
.outer li img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Will fix this.

```css
.outer {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
.outer li,
.outer li img{ display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
    <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA"></li>
     <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
 <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter: might be bothered to explain your reasons?